# I want to replace text in HTML page with values but without replaceAll method as it is not availbe

Tags: java, string, mobile, replace

I'm building adf mobile Application with jdeveloper 11.1.2.4
and i've html code that is saved in a bundle and i want to write this code to html page in a mobile device but before writing this code i want to replace some value for example **to replace F_NAME with the employee first name string that i have in a variable.**
but when i try to use **htmlCode.replaceAll**
the replaceAll method is not available and i want to replace some text with some values.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the design itself, try it with the Apache Commons StringUtils class.It has some string manipulation methods, including replaceAll.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Download:http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Go for the 3.x version.

Comment: But how can i add this lib to my adf mbile application

Comment: I can take a wild guess, because I do not know anything about that, but a simple search tells me that you should go to project properties > Libraries > Add Library (or Add New).